# Assert\LessThanOrEqual and Assert\Range don't work with Datetime

Tags: symfony, assert

I want to validate my date with `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints` and Doctrine

in my controller I have

```
$user->setMyDate(new \DateTime('tomorrow'));
```

and in my entity

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\LessThanOrEqual("today")
 * @Assert\Range(
 *      min = "now",
 *      max = "now"
 * )
 * @Assert\DateTime()
 * @ORM\Column(name="my_date", type="datetime", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
 */
private $my_date;
```

I tried with LessThanOrEqual and with Range, but it doesn't work

Comment: Are you calling the validator anywhere?

Comment: what does mean anywhere? If I change $user->setMyDate('foo'); I have an error, it's not Datetime. **UPDATE** Sorry now understand, yes I call it

Answer (score 0):

Is it a question or is it a statement?
No, they don't.

When any of constraint is initialized, it gets a values to compare from passed options. In you case - it's strings "today" or "now".

So when constraint is applied, the string is being compared with \DataTime object and, obviously, it doesn't work.

But to get what you need you just have to create a custom constraint.

Something like this:

```
class RageDateTime extends Range
{
    public $min;
    public $max;

    public function __construct($options = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($options);
        $this->max = new \DateTime($this->max);
        $this->min = new \DateTime($this->min);
    }

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return 'RangeValidator';
    }        
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but in documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/LessThanOrEqual.html#comparing-dates it is different